# Combine two columns into one and add column with identifier contingent on former column membership

Tags: r

I have a df like so:

```
df<- data.frame(node1= c("A", "B","C","A", "B","C"), node2= c("Z", 
"X", "Y","Z", "X", "Y"))
```

I would like to create a dataframe like so:

```
output<-data.frame(node= c("A", "B","C","A","B","C","Z","X","Y","Z", 
"X", "Y"), attrib= c("1", "1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2", 
"2", "2"))
```

This way, two factors are joined to one column, however, a second column is created that includes identifiers contingent on the column from which the data originally belonged to.

Comment: `data.frame(node = unlist(df, use.names = FALSE), attrib = c(col(df)))`. Please show your attempts at a solution next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` to reshape the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
output <- df %>%
  gather(attrib, node) %>%
  mutate(attrib = sub("node", "", attrib)) %>%
  select(node, attrib)
```